# React Native Endless Loop

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I am using the react-native IOSTabbar like the following example:

```
  render: function() {
     return (
       <TabBarIOS
         tintColor="white"
         barTintColor="#D7DF01">
         <TabBarIOS.Item
           title="All"
           icon={require('./x.png')}
           selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'x'}
           onPress={() => {
             this.setState({
               selectedTab: 'x',
             });
           }}>
           {this._renderContent(this.state.selectedTab)}
         </TabBarIOS.Item>
         <TabBarIOS.Item
           icon={require('./y.png')}
           title="Incoming"
           selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'y'}
           onPress={() => {
             this.setState({
               selectedTab: 'y'
             });
           }}>
           {this._renderContent(this.state.selectedTab)}
         </TabBarIOS.Item>
         <TabBarIOS.Item
           icon={require('./z.png')}
           title="Outgoing"
           selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'z'}
           onPress={() => {
             this.setState({
               selectedTab: 'z'
             });
           }}>
            {this._renderContent(this.state.selectedTab)}
         </TabBarIOS.Item>
       </TabBarIOS>
     );
   },
```

Within the _renderContent method I am executing a SQLLite Select but this ends in an endless loop..Is that normal for the TabBar ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: It would probably help if you post the actual code of the _renderContent method. Have you tried if the endless loop still persists if you just render a simple Text element in each TabBar item?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the SQLLite call within the render. Use the lifecycle methods, because every time the component renders it will:

- make the call
- update some state
- trigger another render

and so on.

Why don't you try to put the call in the componentDidMount method, assign the result to the state like `setState({ tab1Content: sqliteResult })` and then call the _renderContent with the tab1Content state